# AWS Api Gateway

Tags: lambda, aws-api-gateway

All,

I'm working on a Proof Of Concept.

Front-end is a web application. Server side is Java/C# and database is postgres.
I want to front-end the REST API's (EC2) with API Gateway.

UseCase: Update Profile

Whenever a user updates his/her profile updateProfile(APIGateway) is called, which in-turn calls a REST API in EC2 and updates the profile table in the database.

At the sametime, I want updateProfile(APIGateway) to invoke a kinesis stream which feeds into Lambda and eventually to an Audit Table in postgres / DynamoDB.

These are the 2 flows that I want to accomplish

API Gateway->EC2->RDS
API Gateway->Kinesis->FireHose->Lambda->RDS/DynamoDB

Is it possible to setup one API that handles both the flows that I mentioned above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to setup one API Gateway stage to achieve both. When you configure an API Gateway, you can create Resource -> Method (e.g; users/list).

At each method, you can define to which the request should be routed. This can be EC2 instance, Kinesis Stream or anything else supported by API Gateway.

e.g; You can say ***users/list*** should point to EC2 instance while ***users/update*** should point to Kinesis Stream.

Comment: Thanks Ashan for your response. I guess my question was not clear. I wanted to have "users/update" API being serviced by an EC2 REST webservice and at the same time "users/update" being sent to Kinesis

Comment: To expand on this, I thought of using Kinesis to capture all incoming/outgoing traffic on API Gateway. what is the best way to capture the traffic ?